# Convert OMI/AURA No2 data from molecules/cm2 to micrograms/m3 (µg/m3)

Tags: satellite, atmospheric-correction, environmental-monitoring

Currently, I am working on OMI/AURA NO2 data which is in molecules/cm2. I need to convert it to micrograms/m3 (µg/m3) to compare with the O3 concentrations. I have gone through the user guide for OMI data, but couldn't find anything related to the units & conversion.

Comment: Hii @xunilk I really appreciate your help. I was doing it for the Tropospheric column so I assume the thickness/ depth would be 10km in my case.  But I have a query, The distribution of pollutant concentrations would not be the same for the total column profile right. It may be more at ground level near the emission heights and low when gradually moving to higher levels of the troposphere. Maybe a 3D distribution model could give more accurate height to concentration profile.  Any information on how to do this 3d distribution modeling could be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are interested to compare NO2 data which is in molecules/cm² with the O3 concentrations in µg/m3 you need several assumptions. First, based in [this link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S5P_NRTI_L3_NO2#bands), I assumed that you are referring to stratospheric vertical column of NO2. This column varies with latitude. Colder regions and seasons lead to a thinner stratosphere due to gas compression. I assumed that its thickness is 30 km (3x10⁶ cm) based in [this link](https://sciencing.com/thick-thin-earths-atmosphere-19740.html). So, molecules/cm² are 3x10⁶ molecules/cm³ for a vertical column of 30 km. Now, you need to consider Avogadro's number (6.02x10²³ molecules/mol), molecular weight of NO2 (46 g/mol), conversion of grams in µg (1 g = 10⁶ µg) and conversion of cm³ in m³ (1 m³ = 10⁶ cm³). Combining all of them (I employed factor method), you got a conversion factor of 2.29x10⁻⁴ for converting values from molecules/cm² to µg/m³ based in these assumptions. Conversions can be obtained by map algebra, from your original maps, by using this conversion factor.

However, you should revise above calculations for discarding any error in arithmetic manipulation.